# JpaRepository making unexpected updates

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a two repositories that extend JpaRepository, associated by a @OneToMany relationship.

I find that when I add a new child and call the save() method not only does the new child get saved but both the parent AND all the children I have attached get updated, even though they're not dirty.

Is that expected?

Parent:

```
@ToString(callSuper=true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id", "version", "exchangeName"}, callSuper=false, doNotUseGetters=true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Exchanges") // uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"mask", "group"})}
public class ExchangeDbo extends Auditable<String> {
  Id @GeneratedValue    
  @Getter private Long id;

  @Version
  private long version;

  @Getter private String exchangeName;  

  @Column(unique = true)
  @Getter private String exchangeNameLowercase;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exchange", 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true, 
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //temp change fetch to lazy
  @BatchSize(size=100)
  @Getter private List<CurrencyPairDbo> listCurrencyPair = new ArrayList<>();
  public ExchangeDbo(@NonNull String name) {
    this.exchangeName = name;
    this.exchangeNameLowercase = exchangeName.toLowerCase();
  }

  public CurrencyPairDbo addCurrencyPair(CurrencyPair currencyPair) {
    CurrencyPairDbo currencyPairDbo = new CurrencyPairDbo(currencyPair, this);
    listCurrencyPair.add( currencyPairDbo );
    return currencyPairDbo;
  }
}
```

Child:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id","version", "currencyPair"}, doNotUseGetters=true, callSuper=false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Coinpairs",
   indexes =  { @Index(columnList = "currencyPair_lowercase", unique = true) 
}
  ) 


public class CurrencyPairDbo extends Auditable<String> {
  @Id @GeneratedValue   
  @Getter private Long id;

  @Version
  private long version;

  @Column(unique=true)
  @Convert(converter = CurrencyPairConverter.class) 
  @Getter private CurrencyPair currencyPair;

  @Column(unique = true, name="currencyPair_lowercase")
  @Getter private String currencyPairNameLowercase;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) //temp change fetch to lazy
  @Getter private ExchangeDbo exchange;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "currencyPair", 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true, 
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //temp change fetch to lazy
  @BatchSize(size=100)
  @Getter private List<TradeDbo> listTrades = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
public String toString() {
  ...
}       

public CurrencyPairDbo(@NonNull CurrencyPair currencyPair, 
        @NonNull ExchangeDbo exchangeDbo) {
    this.currencyPair = currencyPair;
    this.currencyPairNameLowercase = currencyPair.toString().toLowerCase();
    this.exchange = exchangeDbo;
}

public void addNewTrade(Trade trade) {
    listTrades.add( new TradeDbo(trade, this) );
}
```

}

Service routine:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public DboReturns addNewCurrencyPair(ExchangeDbo exchangeDbo, String currencyPairString) {  
    CurrencyPairDbo currencyPairDbo = exchangeDbo.addCurrencyPair(new CurrencyPair(currencyPairString));
    ExchangeDbo newExchangeDbo = exchangeRepository.save(exchangeDbo);

    return new DboReturns(newExchangeDbo, currencyPairDbo, null);
}
```

Comment: No it is not, you micht want to add some code like entities and your service logic

Comment: Thanks @Zeromus.  Done.